# Hadoop examples grep

Tags: hadoop

I just started looking into hadoop and downloaded therefore the current version 4.3.1 of the cloudera virtual machine.

I started looking into the hadoop example grep to get a first feeling for hadoop. I can compile and execute the jar file on a data collection searching for one string without any problems. But as soon as I try to search for a number of strings the execution fails. I'm sure it's just a syntactical issue but I can't figure it out. I tried to following ways:

//works:

```
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output "sample text"
```

//doesn't work:

```
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output "sample text" "sample1" "sample2"
```

//doesn't work:
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output ["sample text" "sample1" "sample2"]

//doesn't work:

```
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output ["sample text", "sample1", "sample2"]
```

Could anyone help me on this? thank you!

Comment: Maybe `hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output "(sample text)|(sample1)|(sample2)"`. The first parameter must be a string with a regular expression.

Comment: works just in the way I was looking for. Thanks a lot!